# Meteor method call returns undefined on the client but not on the server

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

#### UPDATE

I just realized something fundamentally wrong in this approach and that nested callbacks can't return something to its parent callback. I came in late in the JS world and come from the `Promises` era and didn't know this is the problem with callbacks. But I didn't see enough examples for Meteor using promises so I used callbacks instead. However, if this code can be improved I'd appreciate it greatly.

#### Question

So I'm calling a method from the client using:

```
Meteor.call('cart.useProfileAddress', {}, (error, address) => {
  console.info('Address', address) // this returns undefined on client
})
```

This is the method in my `api/carts/cartsMethod.js`

```
export const useProfileAddress = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'cart.useProfileAddress',
  validate(args) {
    //
  },
  run(args) {
    const person = Persons.findOne({'userId': Meteor.userId()});
    // If I do the return here I get the address in the browser as defined.
    // return person.address

    // I'm calling another method under here:
    getClosestStore.call({address: person.address}, (error, result) => {
      // And another one method call here:
      updateCartAddress.call({address: person.address}, (error, result) => {
        // So once all the callbacks are done return the address here.
        // However the problem is I get `undefined` on the client.
        if (!error) {
          // console displays something on the Server but is `undefined` on the Client
          console.info('Returning Address', person.address)
          return person.address
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

What could be the problem on the code above? Could it be because I'm trying to get the value from a nested callback?

Also does anyone know how to avoid these nested callbacks? I know how to do it on `Node` using promises but in Meteor (I'm using `1.4`) I'm still clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem using Promise and the new `async/await` feature of Meteor `1.3+`

```
export const useProfileAddress = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'cart.useProfileAddress',
  validate(args) {
    //
  },
  run(args) {
    return ((async () => {
      const person = Persons.findOne({'userId': Meteor.userId()});
      const storeId = await getClosestStore.callPromise({address: person.address})
      const newAddress = await updateCartAddress.callPromise({address: person.address})

      return newAddress
    })())
  }
})
```

Inside each method I used the [didericis:callpromise-mixin](https://atmospherejs.com/didericis/callpromise-mixin) so that it will return a promise.

Answer (score 4):

Methods can run synchronously on server so you do not need to use callback. Result of method will be returned after execution or exception will be thrown if error occurs. Try this:

```
export const useProfileAddress = new ValidatedMethod({
  // ...
  run(args) {
    const person = Persons.findOne({'userId': Meteor.userId()});

    const result1 = getClosestStore.call({address: person.address});

    // use result1 if you need to

    const result2 = updateCartAddress.call({address: person.address});

    // // use result2 if you need to

    return person.address;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm assuming if you remove the callback from the method call, that makes it synchronous, is that correct? If so, would the client be affected with this approach if the code now becomes blocking?

Comment: Of course, client only receives the result after the two methods are finished

Comment: I got a problem with this approach. `getClosestStore.call` always does async since it's a wrapper of another async call that gets the distance from another api. Is it possible to pass a callback inside a method so I can call at the innermost callback? If all else fails I'm gonna use promises.

Comment: You can not do that because functions can not be serialized, I think you could use promise in `getClosestStore` method

Comment: I actually tried putting the callback function and you are right, thanks for pointing me towards solution!